# How to set false as a value using Boolean in SimpleSchema?

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-collection2

SimpleSchema solves a great general problem but man am I confused by it sometimes.

For instance, I have this value defined there:

```
changedPassword: {
    type: Boolean,
    optional: true
}
```

It tracks if the user has changed his password, and should obviously be either `true` or `false`. However, SimpleSchema doesn't seem to share my view on what `Boolean` means.

Anyway, `changedPassword` starts out not existing at all when someone creates a user, and is set to `true` when he changes his password. The problem arrives when I'm doing a password reset, and the value should revert to `false` or non-existance again. **SimpleSchema doesn't seem to allow any changes to this field except setting it to `true`!**

My method may look like this,

```
changedPassword: function(status) {
  if (status === false) {
    Meteor.users.update({_id: Meteor.userId()}, {$unset: {changedPassword: ''}})
  }
}
```

or

```
changedPassword: function(status) {
  if (status === false) {
    Meteor.users.update({_id: Meteor.userId()}, {$set: {changedPassword: false}}
  }
}
```

but it still won't actually make the change, even when I'm logged in and typing `Meteor.call('changedPassword', false)` in the console.

What the heck is the purpose of that and how can I get around it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got around it by simply making another method:

```
notChangedPassword: function() {
  Meteor.users.update({_id: Meteor.userId()}, {$set: {changedPassword: false}})
}
```

Don't know it wouldn't work with a conditional, though. Looks like a bug. I'll leave this answer here until someone can give a better, more thorough one.